# how to convert shadershop formula into glsl

Tags: glsl, shader

I have been learning some basic of shaders recently and I came up with a great visual tools : [shadershop](http://www.cdglabs.org/Shadershop/)

But I am having trouble to convert the formula I created in this site into glsl.

A simple example, I created a formula in this site:

[image]

And I am able to convert this in glsl:

[image]

And then I moved on, I created a two dimension formula on shadershop :

[image]

But this I just have no clue how to convert this formula into glsl just like I did before.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

UPDATE

I tried again to convert the formula according to @Rabbid76 's advice:

[image]

But still I am having trouble to understan :

1. how to split the formula to U and V
2. how to deal with the matrix in the formula

Comment: You have to do something like this: `float u = sin(st.x .....)`, `float v = sin(st.y .....);`, `gl_FragColor = vec4(u, v, 0.0, 1.0);`

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks for your quick reply, I tried to convert the formula just like you said (see the update of the question) but still can not figure out how to get it done. Would you mind if you can me some more hints ?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula of [shadershop](http://www.cdglabs.org/Shadershop/) can be expressed as follows:

```
vec2  x1x2 = inverse(m) * vec2(x1, x2);
float x    = -sin(x1x2.x - x1x2.y);
```

where `m` is a 2x2 matrix.

e.g.

```
mat2 m = mat2(
    0.1, 0.0,
    0.5, 1.0
);
```

For the formula for the inverse matrix see [www.mathwords.com](http://www.mathwords.com/i/inverse_of_a_matrix.htm) (in GLSL ES 1.00 there is no function for the inverse matrix) :

```
float det_m = m[0][0]*m[1][1] - m[0][1]*m[1][0];
mat2  inv_m = mat2(m[1][1], -m[0][1], -m[1][0], m[0][0]) / det_m;
```

The full fragment shader code may look like this:

```
void main()
{
    vec2 st = 2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy - 1.0;

    vec2 scale = vec2(1.5, 1.5);
    st *= scale;

    mat2 m = mat2(
        0.1, 0.0,
        0.5, 1.0
    );

    vec2 x1x2 = vec2(st.x, 0.0);
    float det_m = m[0][0]*m[1][1] - m[0][1]*m[1][0];
    if ( det_m != 0.0 )
    { 
      mat2 inv_m = mat2(m[1][1], -m[0][1], -m[1][0], m[0][0]) / det_m;
      x1x2 = inv_m * st.xy;
    }
    float x = -sin(x1x2.x - x1x2.y);

    vec3 color = vec3( x, x, abs(x) );
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

See the preview:

[image: preview]

Comment: Why suddenly negative sinus? Why the inverse matrix? Please explain more.

Comment: @clankill3r The negative sine is just for the color mapping, it doesn't make a big difference. The inverse matrix is because the shadershop expression defines how to calculate `(u, v) = f(x1, x2)`. The fragment shader is executed the for each fragment, so the input is u,v and you've to calculate the inverse operation: `(x1, x2) = f(u, v)`.

Comment: How to deal with such an expression? Please help  - https://imgur.com/GcNSFGJ