# Problem going from Shadershop functions to glsl functions

Tags: glsl, shader, glsles

It's a bit related to [how to convert shadershop formula into glsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821891/how-to-convert-shadershop-formula-into-glsl) .
Only the above answer does not provide any explanation.

What I try is:

[image]

Where SineV is:

[image]

and SineH is:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

float scale = 5.0;


uniform vec2 u_resolution;

float sineV(float x) {
    x *= scale;
    return  (sin( x / 0.18 ) + sin( (x - -1.0) / 0.35 ) + 0.25);
}

float sineH(float x) {
    x *= scale;
    return (sin( (x - 0.18) / 0.37 ) + sin( ((x - 0.18) - -0.31) / 0.45 ) + -0.59) * 0.75 + 0.1;
}

mat2 inverse(mat2 m) {
    float det_m = m[0][0]*m[1][1] - m[0][1]*m[1][0];
    mat2  inv_m = mat2(m[1][1], -m[0][1], -m[1][0], m[0][0]) / det_m;
    return inv_m;
}



void main() {

    mat2 m = mat2(0.0, -1.0,
                  1.0, 0.0);

    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy;
    float x1 = st.x;
    float x2 = st.y;

    vec2  x1x2 = inverse(m) * vec2(x1, x2);

    vec2 tmp = m * x1x2;

    float x = sineV(x1x2.x - x1x2.y) + sineH(tmp.x - tmp.y);

    vec3 color = vec3( x, x, abs(x) );
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

But I reached a point where it is just guessing and trial and error.
Hope someone can help.

Comment: @Rabbid76 thanks, I think I did but in a more simple way. I check later, and might upvote. Thanks. Haven's been working on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix in [shadershop](http://www.cdglabs.org/Shadershop/) transforms the input tuple `(x1, x2)` to `(u, v)` coordinates.
The fragment shader is executed for each fragment, each fragment is associated to different (u, v) coordinates. You've to calculate the `x1` and `x2` corresponding to the actual (u, v) coordinate of the fragment. So you've to use the inverse matrix:

```non
(u, v)  = m * (x1, x2)
(x1, x2 = inverse(m) * (u, v)
```

The shader has to sum up result of the `f(x1)` and the result of the `f(x2)`:

```non
x = f(x1) + f(x2)
```

The corresponding glsl code is:

```c
vec2  x1x2 = inverse(m) * st.xy;
float x    = sineH(x1x2.x) + sineV(x1x2.y);
```

The mapping of `x` to the white, blue and black color can be achieved by the empirical formula (I found this out by trial and error):

```c
vec3 color = vec3(x, x, abs(x));
```

For the full shader code see the example (note, the result is stretched to the canvas):

```js
(function loadscene() {    

var canvas, gl, vp_size, prog, bufObj = {};

function initScene() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "ogl-canvas");
    gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
    if ( !gl )
      return;

    progDraw = gl.createProgram();
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        let source = document.getElementById(i==0 ? "draw-shader-vs" : "draw-shader-fs").text;
        let shaderObj = gl.createShader(i==0 ? gl.VERTEX_SHADER : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        gl.shaderSource(shaderObj, source);
        gl.compileShader(shaderObj);
        let status = gl.getShaderParameter(shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
        if (!status) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
        gl.attachShader(progDraw, shaderObj);
        gl.linkProgram(progDraw);
    }
    status = gl.getProgramParameter(progDraw, gl.LINK_STATUS);
    if ( !status ) alert(gl.getProgramInfoLog(progDraw));
    progDraw.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation(progDraw, "inPos");
    progDraw.u_resolution = gl.getUniformLocation(progDraw, "u_resolution");
    gl.useProgram(progDraw);

    var pos = [ -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1 ];
    var inx = [ 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 ];
    bufObj.pos = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.pos );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( pos ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    bufObj.inx = gl.createBuffer();
    bufObj.inx.len = inx.length;
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( inx ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( progDraw.inPos );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( progDraw.inPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 ); 
    
    gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    window.onresize = resize;
    resize();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function resize() {
    vp_size = [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight];
    //vp_size = [256, 256]
    canvas.width = vp_size[0];
    canvas.height = vp_size[1];
}

function render(deltaMS) {

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
   
    gl.uniform2f(progDraw.u_resolution, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, bufObj.inx.len, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
    
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}  

initScene();

})();
```

```html
<script id="draw-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision mediump float;

attribute vec2 inPos;

varying vec2 ndcPos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4( inPos.xy, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<script id="draw-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

uniform vec2  u_resolution;

float scale = 5.0;

float sineV(float x) {
    x *= scale;
    return  (sin( x / 0.18 ) + sin( (x - -1.0) / 0.35 ) + 0.25);
}

float sineH(float x) {
    x *= scale;
    return (sin( (x - 0.18) / 0.37 ) + sin( ((x - 0.18) - -0.31) / 0.45 ) + -0.59) * 0.75 + 0.1;
}

mat2 inverse(mat2 m) {
    float det_m = m[0][0]*m[1][1] - m[0][1]*m[1][0];
    mat2  inv_m = mat2(m[1][1], -m[0][1], -m[1][0], m[0][0]) / det_m;
    return inv_m;
}

void main()
{
    vec2  st     = 2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy - 1.0;
    mat2  m      = mat2(0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    vec2  x1x2   = inverse(m) * st.xy;
    float x      = sineH(x1x2.x) + sineV(x1x2.y);

    vec3 color   = vec3(x, x, abs(x));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
</script>

<canvas id="ogl-canvas" style="border: none"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, I check it out later. My brain needs some rest now.